# Laravel: limit many-to-many eager loading by pivot table data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'd like to limit a many-to-many relation loaded by Laravel eager loading by data located in the pivot table for the many-to-many relation.

table_a

table_b

table_pivot (connects table_a and table_b many-to-many)

Query should return TableA with eager loaded TableB, but only when table_pivot.active = true.

I tried the following:

```
TableA::with(['table_b' => function ($query) { 
    $query->where('table_pivot.active', true); 
    // not sure how to address table_pivot here in the right way
}]);
```

The models are all setup in the recommended way (BelongsToMany relations etc.).

Thanks for any hints on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the wherePivot method in the closure of the with function to fast load a many-to-many relationship in Laravel with a condition depending on the pivot table. Here's how you can change your code to make that happen:

Providing your relationship definitions in your models are accurate:

```
TableA::with(['tableB' => function ($query) {
    $query->wherePivot('active', true);
}])->get();
```